# Pointed ellipse shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, shapes

I'm trying to draw a pointed ellipse shape between two `tikzmarknode` nodes.
Regardless of the ratio of semi-major to semi-minor axis I choose, I can't make the ends very pointy.

My different attempts are below:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\centering
\tikzmarknode{11}{} \hspace{45mm} \tikzmarknode{12}{}
\bigskip\par\noindent
\tikzmarknode{21}{} \hspace{45mm} \tikzmarknode{22}{}
\bigskip\par\noindent
\tikzmarknode{31}{} \hspace{45mm} \tikzmarknode{32}{}

\vspace{100mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
every path/.style={line width=2pt, color=blue,text = black}]
 \node (11-12) at ($(11)!0.5!(12)$){};
 \draw[fill] let \p1=($(12)-(11)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (11-12) ellipse(\n1/2 and 1pt);
 \node (21-22) at ($(21)!0.5!(22)$){};
 \draw[fill] let \p1=($(21)-(22)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (21-22) ellipse(\n1/2 and 0.5pt);
 \node (31-32) at ($(31)!0.5!(32)$){};
 \draw[fill] let \p1=($(31)-(32)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (31-32) ellipse(\n1/2 and 0.25pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All the ellipses have very rounded ends when I'd rather something like in the picture: [image: Very pointy ellipses]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why use elipse rather than simply a curve and its reflection ending in non smooth joins at the ends?

Comment: Lose the `line width=2pt`.  Either that or replace `\draw[fill]` with `\fill`.

Comment: What @JohnKormylo said, why are you using an ellipse (one with a line width of 2pt even) if you want something pointy? You don't really need `tikzmark` here either. You can just do `{\centering\tikz\fill (0,0) to[out=1, in=179] +(right:25mm) to[out=181, in=-1] cycle;\par}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What type of curve would you suggest?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. Those were great suggestions. I was using line width to tweak another element of the picture (not included here).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I do need to use tikzmark in the final version. Thanks for the help though. It worked well.